# temperature of the Broadcom 10Gb LAN controller (BCM57416) on Supermicro motherboards

Tags: local-area-network, nic, supermicro, broadcom

I am looking for information from people with systems with Supermicro motherboards with a Broadcom 10Gb NIC controller chip (BCM57416). Specifically, I would like to find out the NIC temperature IPMI reports on your board (for example, running "ipmitool sensor" or the IPMICFG tool "IPMICFG -sdr").
We have such a system, with the X13DAI-T board, and IPMI reports a NIC temperature of 71C-74C. This seems extremely high -- likely to damage the chip and the board. Other systems, with onboard 10Gb Intel NIC controllers, report temperatures around 45C.
Thanks!

Comment: What does Broadcom say is the normal operating temperature range for the chip?

Comment: I actually did look on the Broadcom website. Surprisingly, I could not find specs for the chip temperature range. I assume they are available somewhere, just not somewhere obvious. I did find a spec for *ambient* temperature up to 55C, but that's not what I am asking about.